# Asset name gets replaced by a dot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm using Ruby on Rails and I'm facing a problem.

When i run my application on the server, I get the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/..self-f28d8f57a7f19b756969e1ff016e5d807dd2b40d26e0e65c1a849f82fa5bd4b8.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/reset.self-6aa5650b7ba29c22295359e84be792256c2c0e09887497329e717eb441b2878c.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />

<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-dae5c5da7223ce739ad497817a3df9ba2fa2840da302653b11558b4f7d98bfc3.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
```

`application.css` is the default CSS that compiles all the SASS into one file, then you have `reset.css` that's added manually by me, and finally you have `..self.css`.

This is the problem. This file is supposed to be `index.scss`. (I know it, because when I delete and create it by myself it loads correctly.)

```
rails generate controller
```

In the SCSS and JS files generated by the method when running the server the name is replaced by a dot.

Can someone help?

Comment: did you run rake assets:precompile? and under your config>environment>development/production, did you set config.serve_static_assets to true?

Comment: doesn't work :/ it doesn't change anything